# No Wifi Adapter Found Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, thinkpad

I recently bought a used Thinkpad T480s and put a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 image on it.  The wifi worked fine for the first time it was on, but now the intel 8265ngw adapter can’t be found. I used lspci and lshw to look for the adapter but it’s like it’s not even there.  I opened up the laptop to ensure the adapter was seated correctly and it looked good. I even swapped out the current wifi adapter with another one.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Some of the older ThinkPad models have a hardware switch on the side that will disable WiFi (and Bluetooth).

Comment: @matigo Unfortunately there is no hardware switch (atleast that I could find) on this model.